# Editing an animation

Tags: animation

I have purchased a model with one long animation track that plays multiple snippets of different character activities. I am not an animator (please forgive me!) and would like to separate the animation track into pieces and create separate blender files for each one.

I can view the desired snippets of animation this way by selecting the appropriate keyframes but cannot figure out how to save a blender (program) file with just the snippet of the animation I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is something I've do frequently and is a simple task. It's done in the Dopesheet, not the NLA.  You make a copy of the Blend file and load that.  Remove all unwanted keyframes and slide those remaining back to frame 1. (or whatever)  Save the file under a new name and one that would describe the action you've left in there.  There would probably be multiple channels so you'd need to take care to box select them all but you wouldn't  need to select them all at once.  Just do them in sections if you like until the only ones left are those between the frames you've already noted.

Comment: Continued from above... Reload the copy and do the same for the next...

If you muck one up, it doesn't matter.  Just go into the copy and do it again.
Hoping that does it for you...

Comment: Thanks so much Edgel3D! Really appreciate the help! We'll give you a credit in our family movie!

Comment: Great Chris!  Do I get media interviews?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For split the animations you can go to Action Editor in Dope Sheet window

[image: Action Editor]

Rename the animation

[image: Rename animation]

Enable the fake user option, this causes the action to be saved to the blend file when not in use by any object. Blender by default delete the elements that are not being used like mesh data, materials, image texture, actions and text. [Data-Blocks Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/data_blocks.html#users-garbage-collection)

[image: fake option]

Now you can duplicate the animation with the "New Action" button. Now you can remove the keyframes you don't need, and rename the current action as well.

[image: New Action]

You can select the stored animations in the dropdown dialog.

[image: Select animation]

Those that have the F in front of them are the actions that have the Fake User option activated.

[image: Fake user list]